# How to use the `attributes` feature without affecting performance?

Tags: php

PHP 8 has introduced the `attributes` feature, and I need to know how to handle it in the right way.
In order to parse `#[someAttribute]`, we need to use `Reflection API`, and I'm afraid it can affect performance. I have many places where I'm going to use `attributes`.
Is it okay to use `Reflection API` at runtime or I need to cache it? I've never used that API before and have no idea if it's okay to use it at runtime or not.

How does `Doctrine` handle entities under the hood? (I tried to study their code, but it's so messy for me there). Does it use some kind of caches or something like this?

I'd be glad to get some detailed explanation about it, and what strategy I should use and why.

Comment: When "and I'm afraid it can affect performance.", Please make a [mre] showing that it actually affects performance....

Comment: "I have many places where I'm going to use". Having had access to attributes for a long time in other languages, I'd say I personally don't use them all the time unless I'm using a framework. The few times I'm trying to do something where attributes help, they are part of a complicated process where 99.9% of the performance problems will be in the process itself. The bulk of my attribute usage otherwise is when I interop with a third-party system, and we use that as a way to describe things. So I'd also assess if you really need to use them, or if there's a better way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.